# Asking for some more time to submit originals

Tags: visas, uk

This is in continuation of previous [question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/138829/supporting-documents-to-convince-can-not-submit-original-invitation-accommodati)

Suppose the visa officer is not happy with scanned copies, can I ask that officer to give me some time to submit the originals?

I can postpone the appointment, but that will delay the visa approval. For just one document (invitation & accommodation letter) I do not think I should postpone the appointment.

Comment: `invitation&accommodation letter` One document for you, but for the visa officer it is important. Don't go by what you think is unimportant. That is surely reduce your chances of getting a visa.

Comment: From my experience that request for originals is just boilerplate nonsense. I have in the past submitted scanned invitation letters and scanned copies of my permanent resident card been issued a UK visa.

Comment: @user56513 Depends on where you are applying from. Chances of fraud are a big possibility in India so the BO might need to see the originals.

Comment: @dumb on what basis did you come to the conclusion"Chances of fraud are a big possibility in India"??

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik You really did get offended very easily. Did you use google ? Read one such snippet. https://www.gov.uk/government/news/uk-government-closing-in-on-fraudulent-agents-in-south-india

Comment: @DumbCoder thanks for the link.. I have nothing to say on this..

Answer (score 1):

> Suppose the visa officer is not happy with scanned copies, can I ask
>   that officer to give me some time to submit the originals?

No. They will simply deny the application or in **very rare** cases contact you for more information they require.

Visa applications are not back and forth correspondence between applicants and ECO’s. Their objective is to approve or deny as expeditiously as possible at the lowest reasonable cost.

Furthermore their philosophy is, if there’s something you want to add or don’t agree with their decision, you should make a fresh application. The days of in person interviews and appeals are gone unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can only hope I will be one of rare situations..

Comment: You have time to get a hard copy from the organizers since we are only in May. Nevertheless many official invitations do not have a **wet** signature. Many invitations from institutions have signatures which are scanned in so I don't think there will be any difference between a quality scan and an original from the organizers.

Comment: My visa interview is on 22nd.. so I don’t have option other than convincing visa officer that this is good enough..

Comment: Does UK embassy still hold interviews? They gave that up long ago in most countries.

Comment: I don’t know if I conveyed to you correctly.. by visa interview I mean on that date I have to go to their vfs office and have to submit documents..